# Convert T-SQL to Fluent Linq C# with the same SQL generated output

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I've the following schema in my database:

[image: Database Schema]

The point is to have for each **User**, his last read datetime per **Thread**.

I can also check this dates by **Forums** & **Universes** with and aggregation if needed.

A **Forum** is considered `Read`, if all **Thread** are `Read`.

A **Thread** is considered `Read`, if the **User**'s `Lastview` is more or equal to the last created post date (from `Post.CreatedAt`).

I've made the following T-SQL request to achieve this goals per **Forums**:

```
SELECT
        F.Id,
        CASE WHEN SUM(V.IsRead) = COUNT(V.IsRead) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsRead
    FROM Forum F
    LEFT JOIN Thread T ON T.Id_Forum = F.Id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
                P.Id_Thread,
                CASE WHEN MAX(P.CreatedAt) < MAX(V.LastView) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsRead
            FROM Post P
            INNER JOIN Thread T ON P.Id_Thread = T.Id
            INNER JOIN Forum F ON T.Id_Forum = F.Id
            LEFT JOIN Thread_View V ON P.Id_Thread = V.Id_Thread AND V.Id_User = @Id_User
        WHERE F.Id_Universe = @Id_Universe
        GROUP BY P.Id_Thread
    ) V ON T.Id = V.Id_Thread
WHERE F.Id_Universe = @Id_Universe
GROUP BY F.Id
ORDER BY F.Id
```

It works perferctly, **BUT**, i now want to create this request from `Linq` using `EntityFramework`... And I'm stuck...

Here is what I've made, but it generates a very much complicated query, and i'm afraid about performance...

```
var viewsQuery = context.Posts
    .Where(p => p.Thread.Forum.Id_Universe == idUniverse)
    .GroupJoin
    (
        context.Thread_Views.Where(v => v.Id_User == idUser),
        p => p.Id_Thread,
        v => v.Id_Thread,
        (p, v) => new { Id_Thread = p.Id_Thread, Id_Forum = p.Thread.Id_Forum, CreatedAt = p.CreatedAt, LastView = v.Max(_v => _v.LastView) }
    )
    .Select(r => new { Id_Thread = r.Id_Thread, Id_Forum = r.Id_Forum, IsRead = r.CreatedAt < r.LastView });

var forumQuery = context.Forums.Where(f => f.Id_Universe == idUniverse).GroupJoin
(
    viewsQuery.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    forum => forum.Id,
    view => view.Id_Forum,
    (forum, views) => new
    {
        Forum = forum.Id,
        IsRead = views.Any() && views.All(v => v.IsRead),
    }
);
```

The SQL output generated by linq is this (slightly edited to be more readable), and it's so ugly...

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    CASE WHEN 
    (
        (
            EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 
                    1 AS [C1]
                FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
                INNER JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT [Extent3].[Id_Forum] AS [Id_Forum], [Extent4].[Id_Universe] AS [Id_Universe]
                    FROM   [dbo].[Post] AS [Extent2]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Thread] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Id_Thread] = [Extent3].[Id]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Forum] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Id_Forum] = [Extent4].[Id] ) AS [Join2] ON 1 = 1
                    WHERE ([Join2].[Id_Universe] = 3) AND ([Project1].[Id] = [Join2].[Id_Forum])
            )
        )
        AND
        (
            NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 
                    1 AS [C1]
                FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
                INNER JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT 
                        [Project3].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
                        [Project3].[Id_Forum] AS [Id_Forum], 
                        (
                            SELECT  MAX([Extent8].[LastView]) AS [A1]
                            FROM    [dbo].[Thread_View] AS [Extent8]
                            WHERE ([Extent8].[Id_User] = 79775) AND ([Project3].[Id_Thread] = [Extent8].[Id_Thread])
                        ) AS [C1]
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            [Extent5].[Id_Thread] AS [Id_Thread], 
                            [Extent5].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
                            [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id], 
                            [Extent6].[Id_Forum] AS [Id_Forum]
                        FROM   [dbo].[Post] AS [Extent5]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Thread] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[Id_Thread] = [Extent6].[Id]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Forum] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[Id_Forum] = [Extent7].[Id]
                        WHERE [Extent7].[Id_Universe] = 3
                    )  AS [Project3]
                ) AS [Project4] ON 1 = 1
                WHERE
                (
                    (
                        (
                            CASE
                                WHEN ([Project4].[CreatedAt] < [Project4].[C1]) THEN cast(1 as bit)
                                WHEN ( NOT ([Project4].[CreatedAt] < [Project4].[C1])) THEN cast(0 as bit)
                            END
                        ) <> 1
                    )
                    OR
                    (
                        CASE
                            WHEN ([Project4].[CreatedAt] < [Project4].[C1]) THEN cast(1 as bit)
                            WHEN ( NOT ([Project4].[CreatedAt] < [Project4].[C1])) THEN cast(0 as bit)
                        END IS NULL
                    )
                ) AND ([Project1].[Id] = [Project4].[Id_Forum])
            )
        )
    ) THEN cast(1 as bit)
    ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Forum] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id_Universe] = 3
)  AS [Project1]
```

**EDIT** : Found a working linq query with the same result, but it is so ugly i'm very afraid about performance...

Answer (score 0):

```
var forumsWhichAreUnread = from forum on context.Forums
                           let isUnRead = forum.Threads.All(thread =>
                                thread.ThreadViews
                                     .Where(view => view.UserId = userId)
                                     .Max(view => view.Lastview)
                                <
                                thread.Posts.Max(post => post.CreatedAt))
                           select new {forum, isUnRead};
```

Translation

Get each `forum` in `context.Forums`

Only give me forums where every single thread...

the largest threadview`.LastView` time is smaller than the Latest Post Date.

Select out those `forum`.

Comment: This is not really what i'm looking for, as I don't want **UnRead** forums, but all forums, with an `IsRead` boolean property.

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work as intended, as it doesn't return unread forums. But mainly, the generated SQL is very heavy and very complicated, i would like to reproduce the same T-SQL query, but using linq. Do you think it's possible ?

Comment: **Edit**: I find a working linq query, but the generated SQL... meh just look at it you will understand :(